# NSNumber object of type long

Tags: ios, objective-c, int, nsnumber

I'm facing a wierd problem with `NSNumber`,When i run the following code,

```
NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithLong:1000];
const char* type =[num objCType];
if (strcmp (type, @encode (long)) == 0) {
    NSLog(@"Type is long");
}else if(strcmp (type, @encode (int)) == 0){
       NSLog(@"Type is int");
}
```

The output is :

> Type is int

Edit: I tried `[NSNumber numberWithLong:1000L]` and `[NSNumber numberWithLong:1000000000]`

But still the same output.

Why is the type `int` here??

Comment: Try with `[NSNumber numberWithLong:1000L];`

Comment: @Wain : Still the output is same.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @Wain : Basically i wanted to maintain the type of data,whether its a int,long,double,float.

Comment: Well, it is actually an integer. Did you try using an actual `long` value?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47554/discussion-between-wain-and-karthik207)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is simple... the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumber/objCType) for objCType says:

> Special Considerations
>
> The returned type does not necessarily match the method the receiver
>   was created with.

Answer (score 0):

This is like asking a `stringWithInt` method to return a string that still knows it is an int. You create an `NSNumber`, you get an `NSNumber`.

Comment: How are types stored internally? When we say its a long,but actually its stored as int.Why does this happen.?Still i don understand.

Comment: NSNumber is a subclass of NSValue that offers a value as any C scalar (numeric) type. What you pass into the constructor doesn't reflect the scalar type it internally represents the value as